# Error in compiling thread in class C++ (Error xthread)

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2015

I am developing an application for Windows in Visual Studio 2015.
The application runs three parallel processes: _thread_EEG (acquisition), _thread_MachineLearning (processing), _thread_Interface (interface).
I'm using the libraries: `<thread>` `<mutex>`

```
class uMotor{
private:
    // Shared memory status
    std::mutex _Mutex_Buffer;
    std::mutex _Mutex_Label ;

    // Shared memory
    Raw  _Shared_buffer;
    char _Shared_label ;

    long _endTime;


    void _EEG            ();
    void _ML             ();
    void _Interface      ();

    static void _Thread_EEG(void *args){
        uMotor *prunnable = static_cast<uMotor*>(args);
        prunnable->_EEG();
    }

    static void _Thread_ML(void *args){
        uMotor *prunnable = static_cast<uMotor*>(args);
        prunnable->_ML();
    }

    static void _Thread_Interface(void *args){
        uMotor *prunnable = static_cast<uMotor*>(args);
        prunnable->_Interface();
    }
   /*
                      ...
    */
}
```

The threads are called in function `uMotor::BCI()`:

```
void uMotor::BCI(){
    const long NUM_SECONDS_RUNNING = 20;

    long startTime = clock();
    _endTime = startTime + NUM_SECONDS_RUNNING * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    // Create threads
    std::thread std_Thread_EEG      (_Thread_EEG      );
    std::thread std_Thread_Interface(_Thread_Interface);
    std::thread std_Thread_ML       (_Thread_ML       );

    std_Thread_EEG      .join();
    std_Thread_Interface.join();
    std_Thread_ML       .join();
}
```

This code looks fine in the IDE (Visual Studio 2015) but when I try to compile it, I get the following errors:

`Error  C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found    uMotor  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread  240`

`Error  C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'    uMotor  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread  240`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whats with the `void *`s?  `std::thread` can take functions that take actual types to maintain type safety.

Comment: Also if the functions require a variable why are you not passing that variable to the constructor of the thread?

Comment: Construct your thread with the function AND the args

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, wrong. You can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threading support was added to C++ exactly for the reason to relieve developer from the need to use unsafe casts, pack values into `void*` structs, etc. With `<thread>` your code should be following (changed one function, you can do the rest):

```
std::thread std_Thread_EEG(&_EEG, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the parameters that shall be passed to your functions to std::thread constructor, only the functions itself. This leads to trying to call `_Thread_EEG()` without parameters, but _Thread_EEG expects one (I'm using EEG as an example, of course applies for the other two, too).

What you actually need is

```cpp
uMotor instance;
std::thread eeg(&_Thread_EEG, &instance); // or use this, if BCI is not static
```

std::thread's constructor is a template, so &instance is passed as uMotor* to _Thread_EEG, which allows you to declare it as

```cpp
static void _Thread_EEG(uMotor* instance);
```

and you do not need the cast any more. I would prefer a reference, though:

```cpp
static void _Thread_EEG(uMotor& instance);
```

Then, however, you need to make the reference explicit for thread template:

```cpp
std::thread eeg(&_Thread_EEG, std::ref(instance)); // or std::ref(*this), if not static
```

By the way: have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) about identifiers starting with an underscore ('_')...

Comment: Your answer have several issues. First, it gives the pointer to the different instance of `uMotor` (than the one used to create threads). This is likely not what OP wants. Second, you are unneccessary resolving scope for std. Since noone is to have namespace std in application code, this is not needed (same for the reference). Third, your statement *::std::thread is a template` is wrong. `std::thread` is **not** a template.

Comment: First issue isn't one - as assuming BCI to be static (thought it was clear from the comment in code), so `instance` is the only instance existing. You did assume, too (BCI not to be static), but declaration in uMotor is lacking, so both asumptions are valid. Second - but it is not illegal either. Still removed it to make you happy... Third: Accepted, it is not the class, only the constructor - adjusted the answer accordingly.

Comment: Background for fully qualifying: In a company I used to work for scope resolution did not work correctly due to clashing sub-namespaces and usage of not fully qualified identifiers within a used library and some extension library we wrote on our own. Needed to change our own sub namespace, consequence was a rule to only use fully qualified identifers within library code. It was not my invention, but I tend to stick with it still today...

Comment: Everyone has some bad experiences. But you have to be careful when you provide answers here - your code has a chance of being copypasted multiple times, so you'd better make it good code.

Comment: On the other hand: Fully qualifying does not break anything anywhere. Does it make bad code then? Searching for quarter an hour now, could not find anything stating fully qualifying is bad practice - or bad coding style at least...

Comment: Yes, it is bad. It is not neccessary, it reduces signal-to-noise ration, it's non-standard (so it make your head spin - why is it there? Is it neccessary? is there an std namespace within this one). In short, **BAD THING**. If you do not trust me, you can ask as a question,

Comment: No, not necessary - thinking right about that, it is alike `return (a);`, `return (x + y);` or `if(x < y) return true; else return false;` instead of `return x < y;` (last one the very worst...) - all of which I hate to see...